# If $f(z)$ analytic in the domain $D$ and $f'(z)=0$ so $f(z)=$constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been thinking how to prove that an analytic function $f$ in the domain $D$ is a constant if  $f'(z)=0$ in every point in $D$, but I haven't figured it out yet.

What I was thinking is to use Cauchy-Riemann equations, but it didn't work well...

If this is not true, I would like to know the counterexample...

**Here is what I tried:**

Let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

$\color{blue}{(1)}\text{(Cauchy-Riemann})\begin{cases}
u_y=-v_x\\
u_x=v_y
\end{cases}$

$\color{blue}{(2)}\lim\limits_{\Delta z \to 0}\frac{f(z_0+\Delta z)-f(z_0)}{\Delta z }=0$ for all $z_0$ in $D$

I'm stuck here...

Comment: You need additional assumptions on $D$. Otherwise your domain may contain disconnected sets and take different (constant) values there as an easy counterexample, but most likely you want to have $D$ connected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In complex analysis, a *domain*  per definition is an open connected set $D\subset {\mathbb C}$. Given two arbitrary points $z_0$, $z_1$ in such a domain $D$ there is a path
$$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto z(t)\in D\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$
with $z(0)=z_0$, $\>z(1)=z_1$. The auxiliary function
$$\phi(t):=f\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)$$
of the real variable $t$ has derivative $\phi'(t)=f'\bigl(z(t)\bigr)\>z'(t)\equiv0$; whence $\phi$ is constant. It follows that
$$f(z_1)=\phi(1)=\phi(0)=f(z_0)\ .$$
As $z_0$, $z_1\in D$ were arbitrary, the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

With Cauchy-Riemann: Note that $f' = u_x +iv_x$ at all points. Therefore $u_x, v_x \equiv 0.$ Use C-R to conclude $u_y, v_y \equiv 0.$ Thus $\nabla u, \nabla v \equiv 0,$ so $u,v$ are both constant, which implies $f$ is constant. (The connectness of $D$ was used here.)