# Show that if $f'(z)=0$ in a connected open set in $\mathbb{C}$, then $f(z)=a \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that if $f'(z)=0$ from the function $f : D \to \mathbb{C}$ which $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ is a domain (i.e. open connected set), then $f(z)=a \in
> \mathbb{C}$ ($a$ is a constant in $\mathbb{C}$). The conclusion is it the same if $f'(z)=0$ on any open
>   set?

I think I can use the Cauchy-Riemann theorem, but it's unclear.

Is anyone could explain to me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Use the Mean value theorem.

Comment: I believe this is not a function of complex variables (otherwise the conclusion would be false). If so, then Cauchy-Riemann has no meaning here. Also, I would reserve the letter $z$ for complex variables. Not that it is necessary, but it's like using $n$ for a real variable... ;-)

Comment: Is $a$ real number? How about $f(z)=i$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: A proof exist from this website : http://home.ku.edu.tr/~bozbagci/401Spring14M1-solutions.pdf. However, I want a proof in using the Cauchy-Riemann theorem.

Comment: But the proposition doesn't say that $a$ is real.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the question, but isn't $f(z)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\lvert z\rvert<1\\1&\text{if }\lvert z-5\rvert<1\end{cases}$ a counterexample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f'(z)=0$, then, every directional derivative of $f(z)$ is $0$. Thus,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0,
$$
where $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ are real and satisfy $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. Comparing coefficients, we get $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0$. Then by Cauchy-Riemann equation,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=0,\qquad \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0.
$$
Then follow Problem 1(a) of the website you showed. Or... [If $f(z)$ analytic in the domain $D$ and $f'(z)=0$ so $f(z)=$constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535260/if-fz-analytic-in-the-domain-d-and-fz-0-so-fz-constant) will also help you.

---

Let $R$ be a union of $B(0,1)$ and $B(2,1)$, where $B(a,r)$ is a ball whose center is $a$ and radius is $r$. That is,
$$
B(a,r)=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z-a| < r\}.
$$
Since $B(0,1)$ and $B(2,1)$ are open sets, their union is also an open set. Define $f:R\to\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
f(z)=\begin{cases}
1,& z\in B(0,1)\\
2,& z\in B(2,1)
\end{cases},
$$
then $f'(z)=0$ for all $z\in R$.

Comment: Two balls in example are not connected.

Comment: @runaround I intended to show that the latter proposition is not true.

Comment: Hmm... $f(z)$, I suggested, has derivative $0$, and $R$ is an open set, but not a constant. Is it wrong?

Comment: I'm editing my post, but I feel you are too offensive to threat me. Can't you wait a few minutes?